# What do you call the upside down V character when it refers to a Jacobian Matrix or similar matrix?

Tags: notation, terminology, jacobian, similar-matrices

What do you call the upside down V character when it refers to a Jacobian Matrix?  Not looking for the wedge operator...
specifically, this is what it looks like:
$$\Lambda$$

Comment: capital Greek letter `\Lambda` is $\Lambda$

Comment: that's interesting... i'm been wondering what to call that thing for years..

Comment: I do feel the edit by Parcly Taxel destroys the question (as now the answer is in the question). Anywyas, this could be helpful in general: http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html

Comment: $\Lambda$ is often used for a diagonal matrix where each diagonal element is an [eigenvalue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigendecomposition_of_a_matrix#Eigendecomposition_of_a_matrix)

Answer (score 7):

$\large\Lambda$ is the capital Greek letter Lambda.

To produce it, type `\Lambda` in MathJax.

Note that eigenvalues are often represented by the small Greek letter lambda $(\lambda)$.